# Datagrid sort number - want null last

Tags: vmware-clarity

Is there any way of setting up sort on a datagrid column that is numeric but can be null so that if the user sorts the list it will always show null last
ie
 asc would be 1,2,3,null
 desc would be 3,2,1,null

Useful as a lot of rows will have null value and if clicking the sort then user is focussed on seeing the info that is thee sorted as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns can have a custom sorting function that an app supplies.

I'll list an overview and then leave a stackblitz link to a working app so you can reference working code.

First, define  a `CustomComparator` for the app to consume:

```
import {ClrDatagridComparatorInterface} from "@clr/angular";

class CustomComparator implements ClrDatagridComparatorInterface<any> {
    compare(a: any, b: any) {
      if (a.key && b.key) {
        return a.key - b.key;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
}
```

Next, declare the comparator as a public entity in the component with the datagrid

```
public customComparator = new CustomComparator();
```

Finally, update the template to declare usage of the custom comparator on the column that needs it:

```
<clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'key'"
  [clrDgSortBy]="customComparator">
    Key
</clr-dg-column>
```

Here is a link to a stackblitz with a custom comparator implanted that always return null items last. https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58020609-custom-sorting

Comment: Hmm.. Had tried this, but I was returning 0 instead of null when both keys were null.
Have just tried this in my project but not working. Possibly because I am still on Angular 7.2.5 and clr 1.1.0.
Maybe time to bump up to v8 and clr 2...
Thanks for your help. Will upgrade and retry over the next few days

Comment: Only way to get it working at all is to change comparator to only "return a.key - b.key" ie. not returning null. In which case sort asc has nulls at top and desc has nulls at bottom.
As said I will try updating a retest

Comment: Finally got back to this. Have created new StackBlitz from above that demonstrates the issue. Above only works because of the starting oreder of the data ie nulls at end. If you put nulls at the start you will see that they do NOT get moved or sorted.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58020609-custom-sorting-yyoepa

Comment: Hippeelee @hippeelee wondering whether you saw the above. My updated stackblitz shows issue with datagrid sorting that I am not sure how to resolve at present. Thanks